# Parsing json having multiple arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsdictionary

I am stuck with `JSON` parsing in my code. I tried a lot but could not figure out what is going wrong.

This is my `JSON` response

```
[{

    "order": {
        "transaction_id": "bFnRjTPYfD",
        "status": 0,
        "created_at": "2015-04-22 09:35:35"
    }

}, {

    "order_items": [{
        "item_id": 1,
        "item_name": "Potato",
        "item_description": null,
        "item_salesprice": 14,
        "item_imagepath": "\/uploads\/veggies\/potato.jpg",
        "order_quantity": "4 Kg",
        "order_price": 69.99
    }, {

        "item_id": 2,
        "item_name": "Tomato",
        "item_description": null,
        "item_salesprice": 18,
        "item_imagepath": "\/uploads\/veggies\/tomato.jpg",
        "order_quantity": "6 Kg",
        "order_price": 79.99
    }]

}]
```

I want to extract transaction id and item name. Can you please help me with this?

Update Answer:

```
NSDictionary *Order=[JSONData ValueForKey:@"Order"]; 

NSString *transaction_id=[Order ValueForKey:@"Transaction_id"];
```

Comment: I would be nice to watch some of your tries, so we can help you better.

Comment: Please try something and then post your question. Instead of posting the JSON Log and ask others to parse JSON..!

Comment: The code you added as answer will crash.

Comment: @user3659166 hey.. everyone trying to help you so why not you accept any answer. if you are not satisfied with answer tell me. will update it.

Answer (score -1):

Try it.. For Transaction id..

```
NSDictionary *Order=[JSONData ObjectForKey:@"Order"]; 

NSString *transaction_id=[Order ValueForKey:@"Transaction_id"];
```

and For item_id try,...

```
NSDictionary *item=[JSONData objectForKey:@"order_items"]; 

NSArray *item_id=[Order ValueForKey:@"item_name"];
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75938/discussion-on-answer-by-ashok-londhe-parsing-json-having-multiple-arrays).

Comment: No intention to start a chat: this code will crash for wrong method name and using KVC methods instead or NSDictionaries methods right yield unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

You can get `transaction_id` by this way,

```
NSDictionary *OrderJson=[jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary *OrderDic = [OrderJson valueForKey:@"order"];
NSString *transactionId=[OrderDic objectForKey:@"transaction_id"];
```

`ItemNames` are in array, you can get it by `for` loop, or predicates, Here I show you with `for`

```
NSDictionary *order_itemsJson=[jsonArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSArray *item=[order_itemsJson objectForKey:@"order_items"];
for (NSDictionary *dic in item) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[dic valueForKey:@"item_name"]);
}
```

Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: You don't even know, what I am talking about, do you?

Comment: @vikingosegundo after a long chat in this session I realized you want to explain something else. Lets come up with something so that we can learn more and more. Please explain what you actually want to tell others.. Thanks

Comment: there are hundreds of questions and answers about it. just search for it.

Answer (score -1):

Do the following things, you will get output.

```
    NSString* transectionId = [[[arrayResponse objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"order"] valueForKey:@"transaction_id"];

    NSLog(@"transectionId : %@",transectionId);

    NSArray* arrayInner = [[arrayResponse objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"order_items"];
    for (int i=0; i<arrayInner.count; i++) {

        NSDictionary* dictInner = [arrayInner objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString* itemName = [dictInner valueForKey:@"item_name"];

        NSLog(@"Item Name : %@",itemName);
    }
```

Here you will get `transaction_id` and `item_name`

Hope this help you.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, we are generally used KVC to access the value in objective-c.. i don't know what you are looking for.

Comment: why would you use KVC methods instead of the proper dictionary methods?

Comment: @vikingosegundo, means are you taking about basic objective-c syntex? like array[0].

Comment: no, I am not talking about subscription. time to learn about KVC.

Comment: ya i know that but it is up to developer to provide validation before used. i am here to provide answer which he expected. weather my answer is like o r not like it is up to them.

Comment: so again: why KVC and not the dictionary method that were written for this task?

Comment: Actually i have tested this code and its working fine. if you have better code then please give me. it would be helpful for future.

Comment: Here i used KVC because i am alway used key data type is `NSString`.

Comment: and why not nsdictionary's methods?

Comment: so here in thie example there want be different between `objectForKey` and `valueForKey`. because both have key data type is `NSString`.

Comment: but kvc evaluates the string to see if an KVC operator is present. if not intended this can lead to a crash. But please explain: why would you NOT use the correct `objectForKey:`?

Comment: actually while writing this code, `valueForKey` is came first in my mind because  my key has data type `NSString`.